# Automatic field value update every week in Lotus Notes

Tags: field, lotus-notes, agent

I want to capture the scheduled time of an agent in a field in form. The agent is running on every Friday evening. When the agent runs, the field will update its value as the running time of the agent. How can I do it? For example, this Friday the field value will be 04.03.2016 and next Friday its value will be 11.03.2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And in LotusScript it would look like this.

```
set DateTime = new NotesDateTime(now)
call DateTime.AdJustDays(7)
DateTime.DateOnly=true
call NotesDocument.replaceItemValue("Field",DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, for those of us who prefer one-liners:

Call NotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Field",Evaluate("@Adjust(@Today; 0; 0; 7; 0; 0; 0)"))